# Database design with multiple Person-like relations

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-relationship

I have a database with relations `Witness`, `PoliceOfficer`, `Suspect`, and many other person-like relations. Often the same person can figure in multiple relations as a police officer could be a suspect in some cases. Would it make sense to make another relation `Person` to store all person relevant data and just point at the person objects in all my person-like relations?

Comment: That would definitely help `normalize` you data. You could put the common attributes of all person like entities into the `Person` relation and access them by using `Person`'s `PK` as `FK` in all other relevant relations.

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with @Guranjan's comment.

Also consider whether a person can have multiples of the same role, and in what circumstances. You may have a `person` who is a `Suspect` in more than one `case`. So, each `case` can have many suspects, witnesses and officers, and each of those points to a unique person.

So, the tables would be:

```
case
  case-id
  crime-description
  date
  time
  etc

case-person
  case-id
  person-id
  type (witness, suspect, officer)

person
  person-id
  name
  dob
  address
  etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your use case, but it would make sense to model it using a few tables: `Person`, `Role` would be the dimension tables - `Person` containing the details you need to store on the individuals (name, address, dob etc) `Role` containing the information relating to all possible roles (Witness, Police Officer, Suspect etc).

You'll need a fact table as well, joining these two for a a particular `Scenario` so for example:

Person 1 - in scenario 1 - is a Police officer

Person 2 - in scenario 1 - is a Witness

Person 3 - in scenario 2 - is a Suspect

Person 1 - in scenario 2 - is a Witness

Person 2 - in scenario 2 - is a Witness

The `Scenario` table would contain the Person and Role keys

Comment: I like the idea of having a relation for all roles. But what about attributes which are specific for some roles? Where can I store the police officers rank etc.?

Comment: You should have a different role for each police officer rank rank. That way you can Person 1 can be sergeant (role 1) in Scenario 1 and inspector (role 2) in Scenario 2 following a promotion